# Cannot read property "varname" of undefined - Format of Data issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I am using AJAX to call data from a Coldfusion cfc. I am receiving the data from the cfc; however, when I try to apply the data to an object, I am getting an error in the console,

> Cannot read property 'myvarname from cfc' of undefined

Here is the code that I am using:

```
// find value of id and name
$j(".dig3").on("click", function(e) {
    var ProgramId = '<cfoutput>#SESSION.id#</cfoutput>';
    $j.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'cfc/cfc_myCFC.cfc?method=qProgram&returnformat=json',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            program_id: ProgramId
        },
        success: function(data) {        
            $j("#programID").val(data[i].ProgramId); 
            $j("#mailform-input-myvarname").val(data[i].myvarname);       
        }
    });

    $j("#formName").dialog("open");
});
```

Am I structuring something wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your issue is the `console.log` calls at the end of the click handler. The `$.ajax` call is asynchronous, so at the point you call them `data` has no value. You need to put all code that relies on the result of the request within the `success` callback

Comment: Appreciate the response Rory. I removed the console code. The error appears to be occurring on this line  $j("#programID").val(data[i].ProgramId); . Isn't that within the success callback?

Comment: It is, yes. Could you edit your question to include the format of the returned `data`

Comment: I have completed your request

Comment: I can't see the code in the edit?

Comment: I edited the title and removed the console code. It should be different

Comment: I think there is a conflict with core.js When I remove it and replace it with jquery.js it works but the rest of the template breaks...

Comment: Okay... I narrowed it down to a jQuery Form Plugin. If I remove the Plugin from the core.js it works.... It is a plugin from > http://malsup.com/jquery/form/